# Solving a nonlinear system of ODE with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, physics, nonlinear

I have been trying to solve the following system of ODE with initial values using the function DSolve. My code is :

```
system = {x''[t] == ((((B0 k) x[t] + B0) q)/m) y'[t],  y''[t] == -((((B0 k) 
x[t] + B0) q)/m) x'[t]};
initialvalues2 = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 10^4, y'[0] == 0};
solution = DSolve[Join[system, initialvalues2], {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

`B0, k, q` and `m` are constants defined later in the code.

However, Mathematica keeps returning the system without providing any answer. 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It may be of use to note that `Derivative[1][x][t]^2 + Derivative[1][y][t]^2` is a constant of the motion.

Comment: This is a ***nonlinear*** system.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on my comment, considerable progress can be made as follows.  First, the constant of the motion given in my comment is derived by

```
system = Map[Factor, system, Infinity] /. B0 q/m -> b
(* {Derivative[2][x][t] == b (1 + k x[t]) Derivative[1][y][t], 
    Derivative[2][y][t] == -b (1 + k x[t]) Derivative[1][x][t]} *)
```

to combine multiple constants.  Then,

```
Simplify[Subtract @@@ system.{x'[t], y'[t]}];
Simplify[2 Integrate[%, t]];
% == (% /. t -> 0 /. {Derivative[1][x][0] -> 10000, Derivative[1][y][0] -> 0})
(* Derivative[1][x][t]^2 + Derivative[1][y][t]^2 == 100000000 *)
```

Then, as noted by Alexei Boulbitch, the two ODEs in `system` are readily combined to give

```
system[[1]] /. y'[t] -> Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2]
(* Derivative[2][x][t] == b (1 + k x[t]) Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2] *)
```

However, at this point we shift the zero point of `x[t]` by `1/k` and only then solve the resulting equation.  (Of course, the initial condition on `x[0]` also must be shifted to `1/k`.)

```
Flatten@DSolve[Derivative[2][x][t] == b k x[t] Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2], 
    x[t], t]
(* x[t] -> InverseFunction[-((2 I EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[(b k)/(20000 + 2 C[1])] #1], 
   (10000 + C[1])/(-10000 + C[1])] Sqrt[2 + (b k #1^2)/(-10000 + C[1])] 
   Sqrt[1 + (b k #1^2)/(20000 + 2 C[1])])/
   (Sqrt[(b k)/(10000 + C[1])] Sqrt[400000000 - 4 C[1]^2 - 4 b k C[1] #1^2 
   - b^2 k^2 #1^4])) &][t + C[2]] *)
```

plus a second solution with is the negative of the first.  They are much simpler expressions.

I should add that the two constants `C` can be evaluated after inverting the solution above, applying the boundary conditions, and performing a bit of algebra.

**Alternative Derivation with Constants Determined**

From my perspective, it is simpler and more instructive to solve the ODE using `Integrate` twice, each time evaluating the resulting constant of integration.  Begin with

```
eq = (#/y'[t]) & /@ Simplify[system[[1]] /. x[t] -> x[t] - 1/k] /. 
    y'[t] -> Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2]
(* b k x[t] == Derivative[2][x][t]/Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2] *)
```

Note that the zero point of `x[t]` is shifted by `1/k`, as above.  Doing so enormously simplifies subsequent results.  Next `Integrate` `eq` and add a constant of integration (equivalent to `C[1]` above).

```
i1 = Integrate[# x'[t], t] & /@ eq;
i1[[1]] = i1[[1]] + c1; i1
(* c1 + 1/2 b k x[t]^2 == -Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2] *)
```

Now, apply the boundary conditions to determine and eliminate `c1`.

```
Flatten@Solve[i1, c1] /. t -> 0 /. {x'[0] -> 10000, x[0] -> 1/k}
(* {c1 -> -(b/(2 k))} *)
i1 = i1 /. %
(* -(b/(2 k)) + 1/2 b k x[t]^2 == -Sqrt[100000000 - Derivative[1][x][t]^2] *)
```

Next, `Solve` this equation for `x'[t]`, so that `Integrate` can again be applied.  (For now, consider only the first solution from `Solve`.)

```
eq2 = Equal @@ (Solve[i1, x'[t]][[1, 1]]);
eq2 = eq2[[1]]/eq2[[2]] == 1
(* -((2 k Derivative[1][x][t])/
   Sqrt[-b^2 + 400000000 k^2 + 2 b^2 k^2 x[t]^2 - b^2 k^4 x[t]^4]) == 1 *)
i2 = Reverse[Integrate[# , t] & /@ eq2];
i2[[2]] = i2[[2]] + c2; i2
(* t == c2 + (2 I k EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-((b k^2)/(b - 20000 k))] x[t]], 
  (b - 20000 k)/(b + 20000 k)] Sqrt[1 - (b k^2 x[t]^2)/(b - 20000 k)]
  Sqrt[1 - (b k^2 x[t]^2)/(b + 20000 k)])/(Sqrt[-((b k^2)/(b - 20000 k))]
  Sqrt[-b^2 + 400000000 k^2 + 2 b^2 k^2 x[t]^2 - b^2 k^4 x[t]^4]) *)
```

A substantial simplification now can be obtained by using the identity,

```
Sqrt[1 - (b k^2 x[t]^2)/(b - 20000 k)] Sqrt[1 - (b k^2 x[t]^2)/(b + 20000 k)] == 
    Sqrt@Expand[-(b - 20000 k - b k^2 x[t]^2) (b + 20000 k - 
    b k^2 x[t]^2)] Sqrt[-1/(b - 20000 k)] Sqrt[1/(b + 20000 k)]
```

Applying it yields

```
(* t == c2 + (2 I EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-(b/(b - 20000 k))] k x[t]], 
    (b - 20000 k)/(b + 20000 k)])/Sqrt[b (b + 20000 k)] *)
```

Finally, determine and eliminate `c2`, and shift the zero point of `x[t]` back.

```
Simplify[Flatten@Solve[i2 /. t -> 0 /. x[0] -> 1/k, c2], k > 0 && b > 0]
(* {c2 -> -((2 I EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-(b/(b - 20000 k))]], (b - 20000 k)/
   (b + 20000 k)])/Sqrt[b (b + 20000 k)])} *)
i2 = Simplify[i2 /. % /. x[t] -> x[t] + 1/k]
(* t == -((2 I (EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-(b/(b - 20000 k))]], 
   (b - 20000 k)/(b + 20000 k)] - 
   EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-(b/(b - 20000 k))] (1 + k x[t])], 
   (b - 20000 k)/(b + 20000 k)]))/Sqrt[b (b + 20000 k)]) *)
```

(Note that the second solution from `Solve`, alluded to earlier, results in the negative of the expression just obtained.)  These results, although cumbersome, do provide analytical expressions for the limits on `x[t]` and for its oscillation period.

```
xlim = Solve[b/(b - 20000 k) k^2 x[t]^2 == (b + 20000 k)/(b - 20000 k), x[t]]
(* {{x[t] -> -(Sqrt[b + 20000 k]/(Sqrt[b] k))}, {x[t] -> Sqrt[b + 20000 k]/(Sqrt[b] k)}} *)

period = Simplify[2 Simplify[Subtract @@ (i2[[2]] /. x[t] -> x[t] - 1/k /. %)], 
    k > 0 && b > 0]
(* -((8 I EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-((b + 20000 k)/(b - 20000 k))]], 
   (b - 20000 k)/(b + 20000 k)])/Sqrt[b (b + 20000 k)]) *)
```

To illustrate these results graphically, consider the case `{b -> 1, k -> 1}`.

```
b1k1 = i2 /. {b -> 1, k -> 1} /. x[t] -> x;
shift = % /. {b -> 1, k -> 1};
Show[ParametricPlot[{shift # + (2 Mod[#, 2] - 1) b1k1[[1]], x}, 
    {x, -1 - Ceiling[#, 6] Sqrt[20001], -1 + Sqrt[20001]}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {t, x}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 5], PlotRange -> {{0, .2}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

**Numerical Solution**

The corresponding numerical solution can be obtained without difficulty.

```
system = {x''[t] == ((((B0 k) x[t] + B0) q)/m) y'[t], 
    y''[t] == -((((B0 k) x[t] + B0) q)/m) x'[t]} /. {B0 -> 1, q -> 1, m -> 1, k -> 1};
initialvalues2 = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 10^4, y'[0] == 0};
solution = Flatten@NDSolve[{system, initialvalues2}, {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]}, 
    {t, 0, 2}];
```

Plotting `x[t] /. solution` gives a figure identical to that obtained from the analytical solution above.  For completeness, all four numerical curves are given by

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, .2}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x'[t], y'[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, .2}]
```

[image]

I would close by observing that, while an analytical solution indeed can be obtained, a numerical solution is easier to derive and probably is more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Making use of the note of @bbgodfrey we easily reduce this system to a single equation. I have chosen the case with the sign + in front of the radical:

```
eq = x''[t] == ((((B0 k) x[t] + B0) q)/m) *Sqrt[10^8 - x'[t]^2];
```

Then DSolve returns two solutions, which are rather heavy. I write here the first of them:

```
DSolve[eq, x[t], t]

(*  x[t] -> InverseFunction[-((4 I m (Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
              2 I k m C[1])] + 
           Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))]) EllipticF[
          ArcSin[\[Sqrt]((I (I B0^2 q^2 + 
                  I Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])]
                    Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))] + 
                  B0 q (-Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
                    2 I k m C[1])] + 
                    Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))] + 
                    k (20000 I m - 2 m C[1] - 
                    Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])] #1 +
                     Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                    2 I k m (10000 I + 
                    C[1]))] #1))))/((Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
                    2 I k m C[1])] + 
                  Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                    2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))]) (Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                    2 k m (10000 + I C[1]))] + 
                  I B0 (q + k q #1))))], (Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + 
               B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])] + 
            Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
               2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))])^2/(Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + 
               B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])] - 
            Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
               2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))])^2] (Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
              2 k m (10000 + I C[1]))] + 

           I B0 (q + 
              k q #1))^2 \[Sqrt]((Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
                 2 I k m C[1])] (Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))] + 
                I B0 (q + k q #1)))/((Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
                   2 I k m C[1])] + 
                Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))]) (Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 k m (10000 + I C[1]))] + 
                I B0 (q + 
                   k q #1)))) \[Sqrt]((I Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + 
                 B0 q + 2 I k m C[
                   1])] (I Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                    2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))] + 
                B0 (q + k q #1)))/((Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
                   2 I k m C[1])] - 
                Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))]) (Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 k m (10000 + I C[1]))] + 
                I B0 (q + k q #1)))) \[Sqrt]((I (I B0^2 q^2 + 
                I Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])]
                  Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))] + 
                B0 q (-Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])] +
                    Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))] + 
                   k (20000 I m - 2 m C[1] - 
                    Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 2 I k m C[1])] #1 +
                     Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 

                    2 I k m (10000 I + 
                    C[1]))] #1))))/((Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
                   2 I k m C[1])] + 
                Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))]) (Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
                   2 k m (10000 + I C[1]))] + 
                I B0 (q + k q #1)))))/(B0 k q Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 
            2 k m (10000 + I C[1]))] (Sqrt[-B0 q (20000 k m + B0 q + 
              2 I k m C[1])] - 
           Sqrt[-B0 q (B0 q + 2 I k m (10000 I + C[1]))]) Sqrt[
         4 m^2 (100000000 + C[1]^2) + 4 I B0 m q C[1] #1 (2 + k #1) - 
          B0^2 q^2 #1^2 (2 + k #1)^2])) &][t + C[2]]  *)
```

It is so heavy that I doubt that it can be useful.

The solution depends on 2 arbitrary constants. However, I do not think that it will be possible to solve the initial conditions with respect to C[1] and C[2]. It is for this reason probably that Mma returns no answer, if one applies the DSolve with initial conditions:

```
DSolve[{eq, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 10^4}, x[t], t]
```

Have fun!